# XML selectNodes using Classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic

XML problem that's got me stumped, but is probably very simple...

The XML is like:

```
    <header>
    <createdOn>16 Sep 2009</createdOn>
    <createdBy>Jez</createdBy>
</header>
<agents>
    <agent>
            <agentDetails>
                    <agentName>text</agentName>
                    <agentTelephone>text</agentTelephone>
            </agentDetails>
            <properties>
                    <property>
                            <propertyid>number</propertyid>
                            <address>
                                    <number>1</number>
                                    <street>High St</street>
                                    <postcode></postcode>
                                    <country>UK</country>
                            </address>
                            <price>
                                    <category>text</category>
                                    <price>number</price>
                                    <reference>text</reference>
                            </price>
                            <description>
                                    <propertyType>House</propertyType>
                                    <bedrooms>2</bedrooms>
                                    <bathrooms>1</bathrooms>
                                    <sleeps>
                                    <briefDescription>text</briefDescription>
                                    <addDescription>long-text</addDescription>
                                    <floorSize>
                                            <size>80</size>
                                            <type>sq. mt</type>
                                    </floorSize>
                                    <bullets>
                                            <bullet>No Of Bedrooms : 2</bullet>
                                            <bullet>Condition : Habitable</bullet>
                                            <bullet>Land Size (M2): 2,000</bullet>
                                    </bullets>
                            </description>
                            <images>
                                    <image>
                                            <thumbnail>URL</thumbnail>
                                            <image>URL</image>
                                            <alttext></alttext>
                                    </image>
                                    <image>
                                            <thumbnail>URL</thumbnail>
                                            <image>URL</image>
                                            <alttext></alttext>
                                    </image>
                            </images>
                            <links>
                                    <link>
                                            <type>text</type>
                                            <url>url</url>
                                    </link>
                                    <link>
                                            <type>text</type>
                                            <url>url</url>
                                    </link>
                            </links>
                    </property>
            </properties>
    </agent>
 </agents>
```

And the code I would like to use is:

```
    Set NodeList = objXML.documentElement.selectNodes("agents/agent/properties/property")
For Each Node In NodeList
    'I want to be able to extract distinct fields here...
    response.write Node.selectSingleNode("address/street") & "<br/>"
    response.write Node.selectSingleNode("description/briefDescription") & "<br/>"
Next
```

But, I don't know how.

ALso, this could be a problem with, for example, the `<images>` and `<links>` tags.

Suggestions please?

Comment: @Jez: You might consider use XSLT for this sort of task.  Taking XML and spitting out HTML is what is good at.  Takes a bit of getting your head round but the resulting code is much cleaner and faster than the equivalent VBScript code.

Comment: I agree Anthony - I've used XSLT successfully in the past, but in this case I'm not trying to display the information, I want the XML schema. I'm trying to create a function to map any XML file to SQL fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the XML example you've posted is invalid.  It lacks a root element (or has multiple root elements, depending on your point of view). Also, the `<sleeps>` element is never closed.  I think these might be typos in your example?

I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to be able to extract distinct fields here."  Can you give an example of the output that you are after?

Without more information, I can suggest trying some variation of this:

```
Dim NodeList, Node, SubNode
'' # Note: Replace [root] with your actual root level element
Set NodeList = objXML.documentElement.selectNodes("/[root]/agents/agent/properties/property")
For Each Node In NodeList
    '' # Do something useful... ?? Distinct fields??
    Set Node = Node.selectSingleNode("address/street/text()")
    If Not Node Is Nothing Then
        Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(Node.nodeValue) & "<br />"
    End If
Next
```

Does this help?

Comment: That's fantastic Chris! It is the way of referencing the nodes that I was getting very wrong - your example code has helped. Thank you!

(BTW - yep, it's typo's in the example. The document does have a root, but it was simplified for this.)

Comment: +1.  Not just because its correct but because it uses Server.HTMLEncode, if I had a penny for everytime I've seen that missing from code.

Answer (score 3):

The code I'm using is:

```
Set NodeList = objXML.documentElement.selectNodes("agents/agent/properties/property")
For Each Node In NodeList
    Set AddrNode = Node.selectSingleNode("address/street/text()")
    if not AddrNode Is Nothing then response.write AddrNode.nodeValue & "<br/>"
    set AddrNode = nothing

    Set AddrNode = Node.selectSingleNode("address/region/text()")
    if not AddrNode Is Nothing then response.write AddrNode.nodeValue & "<br/>"
    set AddrNode = nothing

    For Each ImgNode In Node.selectNodes("images/image")
        Set ThNode = ImgNode.selectSingleNode("thumbnail/text()")
        if not ThNode Is Nothing then response.write ThNode.nodeValue & "<br/>"
        set ThNode = nothing
        Set ThNode = ImgNode.selectSingleNode("image/text()")
        if not ThNode Is Nothing then response.write ThNode.nodeValue & "<br/>"
        set ThNode = nothing
        Set ThNode = ImgNode.selectSingleNode("alttext/text()")
        if not ThNode Is Nothing then response.write ThNode.nodeValue & "<br/>"
        set ThNode = nothing
    next
Next
```

I hope someone else finds its useful!

Comment: I did. Thanks. Currently using Classic ASP to consume data from Amazon Web Services. Specifically, product search.